# What's the Django User password's encryption method?

Tags: python, django, encryption

In django project, there is `auth_user` table:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and its structure is like this:

[image: enter code here]

You see its length is 128, I don't know whats the meaning of encryption method of the password field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Django uses the **PBKDF2** algorithm with a **SHA256** hash.

For detailed reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/passwords/

Comment: how to convert and store in django user table, if my old php table has md5 password?