# command line login to using django user name and password

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

I have a command-line application and I would like to connect it to a Django Web application. Any ideas about how the user can log in using their Django user name and password from the terminal application?

Comment: You have to write a [custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/) ! And call it in front of your `cla` app

Comment: What do you mean by custom authentication? If there any way to validate the username and password in the Django database from my command line application?

Comment: Yes, the link is above

Comment: @Rvector if I use this I still need to have Django application. What I'm trying to do is create a command-line tool so the users can use their Django username and password to login using the terminal application.

Comment: Ow, for this situation you can simply create your app and force user to use their Django credentials.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886248/whats-the-django-user-passwords-encryption-method What I found, I need some guidance on how to implement this inside the command line tool

Comment: How to force the users to use the Django credentials if I have about 20 users? I don't want to hard code the user names and passwords. Inside my terminal app, I already have a connection to the Django Database. The problem is the authentication.